# Handle files with space in filename and output file names

Tags: bash

I need to write a Bash script that achieve the following goals:

1) move the newest n pdf files from folder 1 to folder 2;

2) correctly handles files that could have spaces in file names;

3) output each file name in a specific position in a text file. (In my actual usage, I will use `sed` to put the file names in a specific position of an existing file.)

I tried to make an array of filenames and then move them and do text output in a loop. However, the following array cannot handle files with spaces in filename:

```
pdfs=($(find -name "$DOWNLOADS/*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1 -t | head -n$NUM))
```

Suppose a file has name "Filename with Space". What I get from the above array will have "with" and "Space" in separate array entries.
I am not sure how to avoid these words in the same filename being treated separately.
Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

-------------Update------------

Sorry for being vague on the third point as I thought I might be able to figure that out after achieving the first and second goals.

Basically, it is a text file that have a line start with "%comment" near the end and I will need to insert the filenames before that line in the format "file=PATH".
The PATH is the folder 2 that I have my pdfs moved to.

Comment: What is the filename with spaces that broke your logic above?

Comment: Can you clarify 3rd requirement more with examples? What do you mean by `specific position in a text file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find downloads -name "*.pdf" -printf "%T@ %p\0" |
sort -z -t' ' -k1 -n |
cut -z -d' ' -f2- |
tail -z -n 3
```

1. find all *.pdf files in downloads
2. for each file print it's modifition date `%T` with the format specifier `@` that means seconds since epoch with fractional part, then print space, filename and separate with `\0`
3. Sort the null separated stream using space as field separator using only first field using numerical sort
4. Remove the first field from the stream, ie. creation date, leaving only filenames.
5. Get the count of the newest files, in this example 3 newest files, by using tail. We could also do reverse sort and use head, no difference.
6. Don't use `ls` in scripts. `ls` is for nice formatted output. You could do `xargs -0 stat --printf "%Y %n\0"` which would basically move your script forward, as `ls` isn't meant to be used for scripts. Just that I couldn't make `stat` output fractional part of creation date.

As for the second part, we need to save the null delimetered list to a file

```
find downloads ........ >"$tmp"
```

and then:

```
str='%comment'
{
    grep -B$((2**32)) -x "$str" "$out" | grep -v "$str"
    # I don't know what you expect to do with newlines in filenames, but I guess you don't have those
    cat "$tmp" | sed -z 's/^/file=/' | sed 's/\x0/\n/g'
    grep -A$((2**32)) -x "$str" "$out"
} | sponge "$out"
```

where output is the output file name

1. assuming output file name is stored in variable `"$out"`
2. filter all lines before the `%comment` and remove the line `%comment` itself from the file
3. output each filename with `file=` on the beginning. I also substituted zeros for newlines.
4. the filter all lines after `%comment` including `%comment` itself
5. write the output for outfile. Remember to use a temporary file.
6. Don't use `pdf=$(...)` on null separated inputs. You can use `mapfile` to store that to an array, as other answers provided.

Then to move the files, do smth like

```
<"$tmp" xargs -0 -i mv {} "$outdir"
```

or faster, with a single move:

```
{ cat <"$tmp"; printf "%s\0" "$outdir"; } | xargs -0 mv
```

or alternatively:

```
<"$tmp" xargs -0 sh -c 'outdir="$1"; shift; mv "$@" "$outdir"' -- "$outdir"
```

Live example at [turorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/CTHjou).

Comment: What does the -z option do for `sort`, `cut` and `tail`? I got errors of illegal option --z on MacOS.

Comment: Option `-z` works like `-0` for xargs -  a line is delimetered by the null byte, not by newline. If you don't have newlines in you filenames - I think you can do it without `-z`. You can check [man sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html), [man cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) and [man tail].

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `mapfile` in conjunction with `gnu` versions of `find | sort | cut | head` that have options to operate on NUL terminated filenames:

```
mapfile -d '' -t pdfs < <(find "$DOWNLOADS/*.pdf" -name 'file*' -printf '%T@:%p\0' | 
sort -z -t : -rnk1 | cut -z -d : -f2- | head -z -n $NUM)
```

Commands used are:

1. `mapfile -d ''`: To read array with NUL as delimiter
2. `find`: outputs each file's modification stamp in EPOCH + ":" + filename + NUL byte
3. `sort`: sorts reverse numerically on 1st field
4. `cut`: removes 1st field from output
5. `head`: outputs only first $NUM filenames

Answer (score 0):

I suppose following code will be close to what you want:

```
IFS=$'\n' pdfs=($(find -name "$DOWNLOADS/*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -I ls -lt "{}" | tail -n +1 | head -n$NUM))
```

Then you can access the output through `${pdfs[0]}`, `${pdfs[1]}`, ...

**Explanations**

- `IFS=$'\n'` makes the following line to be split only with "\n".
- `-I` option for `xargs` tells xargs to substitute `{}` with filenames so it can be quoted as `"{}"`.
- `tail -n +1` is a trick to suppress an error message saying "xargs: 'ls' terminated by signal 13".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bash v4 has an option `globstar`, after enabling this option, we can use `**` to match zero or more subdirectories.

`mapfile` is a built-in command, which is used for reading lines into an indexed array variable. `-t` option removes a trailing newline.

```
shopt -s globstar
mapfile -t pdffiles < <(ls -t1 **/*.pdf | head -n"$NUM")

typeset -p pdffiles

for f in "${pdffiles[@]}"; do
  echo "==="
  mv "${f}" /dest/path
  sed "/^%comment/i${f}=/dest/path" a-text-file.txt
done
```